# I run Python 3.10 and MySQL. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mysql, macos

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "Thsmine2",
    database = "_universidad_"
)

cursorrecup = mydb.cursor()
cursorrecup.execute("UPDATE _universidad_.copias SET id_investigadores =8 WHERE id = 10; SELECT * FROM _universidad_.copias")
mydb.commit()

resultadorecup = cursorrecup.fetchall()
for x in resultadorecup:
    print(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3])
```

I have reduced my problem to these lines, however, there seems to be a problem with the function . I have revised all of my variables and references to the database and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the cursor as it is being executed, rather than over the result.  This code works for me:

```py
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t73955432')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE t73955432 (a float)')
conn.commit()  
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO t73955432 (a) VALUES (%s)', [(1,), (2,), (3,)])
conn.commit()                                      
stmts = 'UPDATE t73955432 set a = RAND(); SELECT a FROM t73955432;'
for result in cur.execute(stmts, multi=True):
    print(result.statement)           
    if result.with_rows:
        print(result.fetchall())                       
    else:          
        print(f'{result.rowcount} rows affected')
conn.commit()     
conn.close()
```

Producing output like

```
UPDATE t73955432 set a = RAND()
3 rows affected
SELECT a FROM t73955432
[(0.557543,), (0.378451,), (0.21963,)]
```